# How to maintain a list of top results from for loop in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am iterating through a list of ~10,000 items. For every item, I process it and get a value. I would like to return a list of tuples with the names and the top 10 values, in descending order of the values.

It looks something like this:

```
top_tuples = []
for item in itemlist:
    cur_value = compute_value(item)
    my_tuple = (item, cur_value)
    if cur_value is > the smallest value on my list:
        remove smallest value from top_tuples
        add tuple to top_tuples at appropriate index #index is based on value
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us how the an item looks like?

Comment: You'll need another loop inside your `for` loop to iterate over the current "best" list.

Comment: maybe separate the processing and the sorting. First process; then sort (using [sort build-in functions](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting))

Comment: the item is a path to a pickled numpy array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT

After receiving a comment on this old answer, I realise the solution I gave is not really good. A better way to do what OP requested is to use a heap with a fixed maximum size. The only requirement is that the item value is put first in the tuple, negated (since Python heaps are "min heaps").

```py
import heapq

NUM_TOP = 10
top_tuples = []
for item in itemlist:
    cur_value = compute_value(item)
    my_tuple = (-cur_value, item)
    if len(top_tuples) < NUM_TOP:
        heapq.heappush(top_tuples, my_tuple)
    else:
        heapq.heappushpop(top_tuples, my_tuple)
```

Note that even though the heap is just a list, it is not sequentially sorted by value. You can convert the heap into the sorted list of top elements, with the correct item value, like this:

```py
top_tuples_sorted = []
while top_tuples:
    neg_item_value, item = heapq.heappop(top_tuples)
    top_tuples_sorted.append((item, -neg_item_value))
```

If you do not want to empty the heap in the process, you could either copy it first, or use `sorted` to get a new sequentially sorted list:

```py
top_tuples_sorted = sorted((item, -neg_item_value for neg_item_value, item in top_tuples), key=lambda a: -a[1])
```

---

OLD ANSWER

Try this:

```
from operator import itemgetter

tuples_gen = ((item, compute_value(item)) for item in itemlist)
top_tuples = sorted(tuples_gen, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:10]
```

Comment: So this requires keeping a list of *all* results, and then displaying the top ten? Wondering if there's an easy way to just keep the "top ten so far" instead.

Comment: @EdwardFalk Yes, the answer was not really good. I added a different heap-based solution.

Comment: Close to my solution. I kept a sorted list of the top 10 results, along with the "score" of the worst item in the list. Any time I found an item with a score better than that worst score, I evicted the worst item on the list, replaced it with the new item, re-sorted it, and updated the score. Works well enough for small N and infrequent replacement. Your solution is better than mine, I think.

Answer (score 0):

without itemgetter:

```
tuples_gen = ((item, compute_value(item)) for item in itemlist)
top_tuples = sorted(tuples_gen, key=lambda tup_gen: tup_gen[1], reverse=True)[:10]
```